# Accumulated Monthly Percentile Calculation in SAS PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a table that closely resembles the following format:

```
ID | Month_ID | Param1 | Param2
1  |    1     |   5    |   10
1  |    1     |   6    |   12
1  |    2     |   4    |   9
1  |    2     |   8    |   15
2  |    1     |   3    |   17
2  |    1     |   5    |   12
2  |    2     |   3    |   11
2  |    2     |   6    |   10
```

I need to calculate a few percentiles (50, 75, 85, 90, 95) for param1 and param2 by ID and month_id, however for each month I need to include all the data for the previous months (so month_id=2 would compute the percentiles for param1 and param2 using the data from month_id=1 AND month_id=2).  I have tried using `proc univariate`, but I can only figure out how to get it for each individual month with the following code:

```
proc univariate data=table noprint;
by ID Month_ID NOTSORTED;
var param1 param2;
output out=Pctls pctlpts  = 50 75 85 90 95
                pctlpre  = param1_ param2_
                pctlname = pct50 pct75 pct85 pct90 pct95;

run;
```

Does anyone know of a way to calculate these percentiles by accumulating months?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with custom month ranges (although assumes the months are all present between min and max for each ID):

Dummy data with different month ranges:

```
data input ;
  do ID=1 to 2 ;
    do month_id=3+ID to 20-ID*2 ;
      parm1=int(ranuni(1)*100) ;
      parm2=int(ranuni(1)*100) ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;
run ;
```

Identify the min and max month for each ID group:

```
proc sql ;
create table range as
  select *, min(month_id) as minmonth, max(month_id) as maxmonth
  from input
  group by ID 
  order by ID, month_id
;quit ;
```

Output each month into the appropriate groups:

```
data output ;
  set range ;
  by ID ;
  do group=month_id to maxmonth ;
    output ;
  end ;
run;
```

Comment: This looks good.  I would then group my proc univariate by ID and group right?

Comment: Did you get the result you were after? If you're happy it solves your problem please do accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do it directly in proc univariate but I would probably expand and regroup the data as below:

```
*dummy data ;
data input ;
  do ID=1 to 2 ;
    do month_id=1 to 12 ;
      parm1=int(ranuni(1)*100) ;
      parm2=int(ranuni(1)*100) ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;
run ;


data expand ;
  set input ;
  do group=12 to 1 by -1 ;
    if month_id le group then output ;
  end ;
run ;
```

This then gives you the a group variable where group=1 contains only month1, group=2 contains month1 and month2 etc.

Comment: I like this approach, except my month_id isn't what you'd assume it is.  It's basically a count of the months between the lowest date in the dataset until the given row's date, so it can go above 12.  Additionally, not all the IDs have data for all the months (so one ID might start at month_id=5 and go to month_id=21, and another might start at 2 and go until 4).

Comment: Hi @Y0dle, I'll put another answer up rather than updating the above answer in case it's of use for anyone else as will try something else....

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to pre-process your data by creating accumulating versions of your params.  This code assumes the whole table is sorted as it appears to be in your example.  It should work sort of like a SQL `group by` that's also accumulating:

```
data accum_table;
    set table;
    by ID Month_ID;
    if first.ID then call missing (Accum1, Accum2);
    Accum1+Param1;
    Accum2+Param2;
    if last.Month_ID then output;
run;
```

Comment: What would I do with the accumulated parameters?  I guess I don't understand how this would help me calculate the percentile.